# Updating many registers of one model requires too much code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I think it must exist an easier way to make a form for updating a list of records of one model.

I need to do all of this to execute a update without a warning `Unpermitted parameters`

in the view:

```
<%=form_tag(action:"update")%>
  <%= fields_for "user_papers" do |up| %>
    <% @papers.each do |paper| %>
      <%= up.fields_for "paper[]",paper do |paper_builder|  %>
        <%= paper_builder.text_field "consum"%> 
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

in the controller:

```
def update
  @papers=PaperConsumption.where(...)
  @papers=@papers.update(paper_consumption_params[:paper].keys, paper_consumption_params[:paper].values)
end

private
  def paper_consumption_params
    params.require(:user_papers).permit(:paper =>[:status,:daconsumo_real,:nucantidad_rec,:paper_correction])
  end
```

- Note that `params.require(:user_papers)` refers to the first `fields_for`
- And `permit(:paper...` refers to the segond `fields_for`

I think there are **too much code** for updating many registers of one table

Isn't it? Can I reduce code?

Thanks (stackoverflow is my only partner in my job :)

Comment: please check out this link, http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: Yes I know that, but my question is not about nested models, what you refer is about using nested attributes for update 1 register with has_many relation, is another case

Comment: The question is ¿how do you update many registers of 1 model in a form?

Comment: can do someting like user_papers[:paper][].each do |paper|   Paper.update(params[:id], {:title => 'Hello world'})
   end